# SQL Query, working with MAX

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table with columns:
population, state, and county

I want to find the county with the max population for each state. I'd also only like to print the name of the county and the max population for that county.

How could I make such a query?

Comment: sqlite3, sorry for not specifying

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a subquery to get the max population for each state and then use that result to determine the county:

```
select t1.county,
  t1.population
from yourtable t1
inner join
(
  select max(population) MaxPop, state
  from yourtable
  group by state
) t2
  on t1.population = t2.maxpop
  and t1.state = t2.state;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de12b/3)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a nested query that uses `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT m1.county, m1.population
FROM mytable m1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 -- No other county in the state has more people
    FROM mytable m2
    WHERE m1.state=m2.state
      AND m2.population > m1.population
)
```

If multiple counties in a single state have the same `population`, *both* counties will be returned.